# which package in linux generate CNAME and TXT record and verify the domain ownership and update record in parent DNS using DnSKEY

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, oracle-linux

these days it's quite common to check the domain ownership using cname and txt records. now can anyone tell me how to do that for my own Linux compute or some linux based packages which will generate `cname` record and `txt` record and verify the domain ownership and update all records based on child DNSKEY to the parent domain?

```
OS: ubuntu 20.04 and 

OS: oracle linux 8
```

just to avoid any further confusion I just want to know the package (open-source) and installation procedure that will deal with this kind of feature.

Comment: Are you asking as a provider of such verification services or as a customer?

Comment: There is no such package.

Comment: @user1686 no. I won't but I am looking to use such a thing to verify for our personal purpose. can you suggest any alternative methods to do so?

Comment: That wasn't a yes or no question. Are you asking about issuing and checking the verification codes for other domains, or are you asking about uploading verification codes that you _received_ to DNS for your own domain?

Comment: from own domains which delegate access or share data after the verifications happen like google does for google search console or AWS ses does for domain validation or maybe yindexer does for building up search indexes or maybe Zoho does before allowing the email access. it is a common process for many vendors.  bind9 possibly allow you to add child dns key ds record and many more.